# JavaScript Error : Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am very new to JavaScript and i was making a tic tac toe game (following a tutorial) but i get an error: Unexpected end of input.

```
let board = [
  ['','',''],
  ['','',''],
  ['','',''],
];

let players = ['X', 'O']

let currentPlayer;
let available = [];
function setup() {
  frameRate(1);
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  currentPlayer = floor(random(players.length));
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (let i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
      available.push([i, j]);
    }
  }

}

function eqauls3(a,b,c) {
  return (a==b && b==c && a != '');
}

function checkWinner() {
  let winner = null;

  //horizontal check
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (equals3(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2])) {
      winner = board[i][0];
    }

// Vertical
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (equals3(board[0][i] == board[0][i] == board[0][i])) {
        winner = board[0][i];
      }
  }

// diagonal

if (equals3(board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2])) {
  winner = board[0][0];
}

if (eqauls3(board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2])) {
  winner = board[2][0];
}


  if (winner == null && available.length == 0) {
    return 'tie';
  } else {
    return winner;
  }
}

function nextTurn() {
  let index = floor(random(available.length));
  let spot = available.splice(index, 1)[0];
  let i = spot[0];
  let j = spot[1];
  board[i][j] = players[currentPlayer];
  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % players.length;
}

// function mousePressed() {
//   nextTurn();
// }


function draw() {
  strokeWeight(4);
  background(255);
  let w = width / 3;
  let h = height / 3;
  line(w,0,w,height);
  line(w*2,0,w*2,height);
  line(0,h,width,h);
  line(0,h*2,width,h*2);
  for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let x = w * i + w/2;
      let y = h * j + h/2;
      textSize(32);
      let spot = board[i][j];
      if (spot == players[1]) {
        noFill();
        ellipse(x, y, w/2);
      } else if (spot == players[0]) {
        let xr = w/4;
        line(x-xr, y-xr, x+xr, y+xr);
        line(x+xr, y-xr, x-xr, y+xr);
      }
      //text(spot, x, y);
    }
  }
  let result = checkWinner();
  if (result != null) {
    noLoop();
    let resultP = createP('');
    resultP.style('font-size', '32pt');
    if (result == 'tie') {
      resultP.html('Tie!');
    } else {
      resultP.html(`${result} wins!`);
    }
  } else {
    nextTurn();
  }
}
```

i cant seem to find a mistake(im a noob)
Can someone help me?

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket for `checkWinner` function. It can be avoided if you use proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

A curly bracket is missing at the end of the "horizontal check":

```js
//horizontal check
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (equals3(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2])) {
        winner = board[i][0];
    }

} // <--- THIS IS MISSING
```